# How to Combine Setter Methods together with redundant code?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, code, setter

```
I'm thinking there is a lot of redundant code in my setter methods, and I'm wondering if there is an effective way to combine them to get rid of some of the redundancies. How should I go about doing that? 

    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import getRecords from "@salesforce/apex/HierarchyView.getRecords";
import getNameUniqueField from "@salesforce/apex/HelpersHierarchy.getNameUniqueField";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

export default class HierarchyView extends LightningElement {
    newRoot = {};
    configRootStr;
    newObject;
    @api outputList;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track constructedNameField;
    @track objectlabel;
    @track nameValue;
    fields = [];

    @api firstChildObject;
    @api secondChildObject;
    @api thirdChildObject;
    @api fourthChildObject;

    @api
    get recordId() {
        let recordId = null;
        if (this.newRoot.recordId) {
            recordId = this.newRoot.recordId;
        }
        return recordId;
    }

    //Generate the JSON string with the record Id retrieved from the getter method (should be the record the component sits on 'the root object').
    set recordId(value) {
        if (!this.newRoot.recordId) {
            this.newRoot.recordId = value;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get objectName() {}
    //setter that sets the value of the object name to the value entered by the user on the hierarchy component and enters it into the JSON string dynamically.
    set objectName(objectName) {
        if (objectName) {
            if (!this.firstChildObject) {
                this.firstChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.firstChildObject.objectName = objectName;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get objectName2() {}
    //setter that sets the value of the object name to the value entered by the user on the hierarchy component and enters it into the JSON string dynamically.
    set objectName2(objectName) {
        if (objectName) {
            if (!this.secondChildObject) {
                this.secondChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.secondChildObject.objectName = objectName;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get objectName3() {}
    //setter that sets the value of the object name to the value entered by the user on the hierarchy component and enters it into the JSON string dynamically.
    set objectName3(objectName) {
        if (objectName) {
            if (!this.thirdChildObject) {
                this.thirdChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.thirdChildObject.objectName = objectName;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get objectName4() {}
    //setter that sets the value of the object name to the value entered by the user on the hierarchy component and enters it into the JSON string dynamically.
    set objectName4(objectName) {
        if (objectName) {
            if (!this.fourthChildObject) {
                this.fourthChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.fourthChildObject.objectName = objectName;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get relationshipFieldName() {}

    //sets the relationship field name as the field name provided by the user in the component, and generates a portion of the JSON string dynamically with the relationship field.
    set relationshipFieldName(relationshipField) {
        if (relationshipField) {
            if (!this.firstChildObject) {
                this.firstChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.firstChildObject.relationshipFieldName = relationshipField;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get relationshipFieldName2() {}

    //sets the relationship field name as the field name provided by the user in the component, and generates a portion of the JSON string dynamically with the relationship field.
    set relationshipFieldName2(relationshipField) {
        if (relationshipField) {
            if (!this.secondChildObject) {
                this.secondChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.secondChildObject.relationshipFieldName = relationshipField;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get relationshipFieldName3() {}

    //sets the relationship field name as the field name provided by the user in the component, and generates a portion of the JSON string dynamically with the relationship field.
    set relationshipFieldName3(relationshipField) {
        if (relationshipField) {
            if (!this.thirdChildObject) {
                this.thirdChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.thirdChildObject.relationshipFieldName = relationshipField;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get relationshipFieldName4() {}

    //sets the relationship field name as the field name provided by the user in the component, and generates a portion of the JSON string dynamically with the relationship field.
    set relationshipFieldName4(relationshipField) {
        if (relationshipField) {
            if (!this.fourthChildObject) {
                this.fourthChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            this.fourthChildObject.relationshipFieldName = relationshipField;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    //gets the 'fields to query' from the first child object
    @api
    get fieldsToQuery() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set fieldsToQuery(fields) {
        let fieldsArr = null;
        if (fields) {
            if (!this.firstChildObject) {
                this.firstChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            fieldsArr = fields.split(",");
            this.firstChildObject.fieldsToQuery = fieldsArr;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    //gets the 'fields to query' from the first child object
    @api
    get fieldsToQuery2() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set fieldsToQuery2(fields) {
        let fieldsArr = null;
        if (fields) {
            if (!this.secondChildObject) {
                this.secondChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            fieldsArr = fields.split(",");
            this.secondChildObject.fieldsToQuery = fieldsArr;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    //gets the 'fields to query' from the first child object
    @api
    get fieldsToQuery3() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set fieldsToQuery3(fields) {
        let fieldsArr = null;
        if (fields) {
            if (!this.thirdChildObject) {
                this.thirdChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            fieldsArr = fields.split(",");
            this.thirdChildObject.fieldsToQuery = fieldsArr;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    //gets the 'fields to query' from the first child object
    @api
    get fieldsToQuery4() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set fieldsToQuery4(fields) {
        let fieldsArr = null;
        if (fields) {
            if (!this.fourthChildObject) {
                this.fourthChildObject = new FormObject();
            }
            fieldsArr = fields.split(",");
            this.fourthChildObject.fieldsToQuery = fieldsArr;
        }
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get nameOverride() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set nameOverride(nameOverride) {
        if (!this.firstChildObject) {
            this.firstChildObject = new FormObject();
        }
        this.firstChildObject.nameOverride = nameOverride;
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get nameOverride2() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set nameOverride2(nameOverride) {
        if (!this.secondChildObject) {
            this.secondChildObject = new FormObject();
        }
        this.secondChildObject.nameOverride = nameOverride;
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get nameOverride3() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set nameOverride3(nameOverride) {
        if (!this.thirdChildObject) {
            this.thirdChildObject = new FormObject();
        }
        this.thirdChildObject.nameOverride = nameOverride;
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    @api
    get nameOverride4() {}

    //sets the fields to query to what the user inputs on the hierarchy component and generates the JSON string with those fields dynamically.
    set nameOverride4(nameOverride) {
        if (!this.fourthChildObject) {
            this.fourthChildObject = new FormObject();
        }
        this.fourthChildObject.nameOverride = nameOverride;
        this.generateJSONString();
    }

    // validates that all the required fields within the hierarchy component have been entered and doesn't allow generating the JSON string otherwise.
    validateChildObject(Object) {
        if (this.Object === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.Object === this.firstChildObject) {
            let keyset = Object.keys(this.firstChildObject);
            let nullValue = keyset.find((value) => this.firstChildObject[value] === null);

            if (nullValue) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (this.Object === this.secondChildObject) {
            let keyset = Object.keys(this.secondChildObject);
            let nullValue = keyset.find((value) => this.secondChildObject[value] === null);

            if (nullValue) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (this.Object === this.thirdChildObject) {
            let keyset = Object.keys(this.thirdChildObject);
            let nullValue = keyset.find((value) => this.thirdChildObject[value] === null);

            if (nullValue) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (this.Object === this.fourthChildObject) {
            let keyset = Object.keys(this.fourthChildObject);
            let nullValue = keyset.find((value) => this.fourthChildObject[value] === null);

            if (nullValue) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //method that generates the JSON string dynamically with every field input (if the object is validated).
    generateJSONString() {
        if (this.validateChildObject(this.firstChildObject)) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.validateChildObject(this.secondChildObject)) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.validateChildObject(this.thirdChildObject)) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.validateChildObject(this.fourthChildObject)) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.newRoot.recordId) {
            //let validSecondObject = false;

            if (this.firstChildObject) {
                this.firstChildObject.child = this.secondChildObject;
            }
            if (this.secondChildObject) {
                this.secondChildObject.child = this.thirdChildObject;
            }
            if (this.thirdChildObject) {
                this.thirdChildObject.child = this.fourthChildObject;
            }
            this.newRoot.child = this.firstChildObject;
            this.configRootStr = JSON.stringify(this.newRoot);
        }
    }

    //gets the image for the nodes in the tree view
    @api
    get imageUrlFieldName() {}

    //sets the image for the nodes in the tree view
    set imageUrlFieldName(imageUrlFieldName) {
        this.configuration += '"imageUrlFieldName":"' + imageUrlFieldName + '"}';
    }

    @api
    get imageUrlFieldName2() {}

    //sets the image for the nodes in the tree view
    set imageUrlFieldName2(imageUrlFieldName2) {
        this.configuration2 += '"imageUrlFieldName":"' + imageUrlFieldName2 + '"}';
    }

    @api
    get imageUrlFieldName3() {}

    //sets the image for the nodes in the tree view
    set imageUrlFieldName3(imageUrlFieldName3) {
        this.configuration3 += '"imageUrlFieldName":"' + imageUrlFieldName3 + '"}';
    }

    @api
    get imageUrlFieldName4() {}

    //sets the image for the nodes in the tree view
    set imageUrlFieldName4(imageUrlFieldName4) {
        this.configuration4 += '"imageUrlFieldName":"' + imageUrlFieldName4 + '"}';
    }

    //wire method that gets the child records from the Config string entered into the component, and fires every time even one field is entered.
    @wire(getRecords, { configObject: "$configRootStr" })
    wiredData({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.outputList = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
class FormObject {
    constructor() {
        this.objectName = null;
        this.relationshipFieldName = null;
        this.fieldsToQuery = null;
        this.nameOverride = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
set objectName(objectName) {
        this.firstChildObject = this.setObject('objectName', objectName, this.firstChildObject);
        this.generateJSONString();
    }


    /**
     * Shared method for setting up form objects.
     * attributeType - The type of attribute that is being set (Object, Relationship Field,Name Override or Field to Query)
     * attributeName - The value to set to the specified attribute
     * formValue - The form element that is being set. Can be null for new form values
     */
    const setFormValue(attributeType, attributeValue, formValue) {
        if(attributeName){
            if(!formValue){
                formValue = new FormObject();
            }
            formValue[attributeType] = attributeValue;
        }
        return objectValue;
    }
```

I've only included an example for setting an object, but the code is the same for the other form elements, with the 'objectName' being replaced by the other types of elements to be set.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is an error to try to assign a value to an @api variable, except inline for a default value if the parent does not provide a value. Since I don't know the purpose of these variables, I'd suggest using private members (prefixed by #), then using a getter/setter, as needed.

Second, you can use the lifecycle to wait for all the data to be available, and should also be updated if any properties change, as long as the inputs are bound to the template somehow. This eliminates all of the if statements from your code entirely.

Third, some variables, like `this.configuration`, seem to be undeclared. I've left that part alone for you to figure out; it will work similar to the parts I've provided below.

Without knowing more behind this code, I've limited my optimizations to be less than ideal, but one that should still work for your use case. Here's my revision:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import getRecords from "@salesforce/apex/HierarchyView.getRecords";
import getNameUniqueField from "@salesforce/apex/HelpersHierarchy.getNameUniqueField";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

export default class HierarchyView extends LightningElement {
  newRoot = {};
  configRootStr;
  newObject;
  @api outputList;
  @api objectApiName;
  @track constructedNameField;
  @track objectlabel;
  @track nameValue;
  fields = [];

  #firstChildObject;
  #secondChildObject;
  #thirdChildObject;
  #fourthChildObject;

  @api get firstChildObject() {
    return this.#firstChildObject;
  }
  @api get secondChildObject() {
    return this.#secondChildObject;
  }
  @api get thirdChildObject() {
    return this.#thirdChildObject;
  }
  @api get fourthChildObject() {
    return this.#fourthChildObject;
  }

  @api recordId;
  @api objectName;
  @api objectName2;
  @api objectName3;
  @api objectName4;

  @api relationshipFieldName;
  @api relationshipFieldName2;
  @api relationshipFieldName3;
  @api relationshipFieldName4;

  //gets the 'fields to query' from the first child object
  @api fieldsToQuery;
  @api fieldsToQuery2;
  @api fieldsToQuery3;
  @api fieldsToQuery4;

  @api nameOverride;
  @api nameOverride2;
  @api nameOverride3;
  @api nameOverride4;

  //method that generates the JSON string dynamically with every field input (if the object is validated).
  generateJSONString() {
    this.newRoot.recordId = this.recordId;
    this.#firstChildObject = new FormObject();
    this.#secondChildObject = new FormObject();
    this.#thirdChildObject = new FormObject();
    this.#fourthChildObject = new FormObject();
    this.#firstChildObject.objectName = this.objectName;
    this.#secondChildObject.objectName = this.objectName2;
    this.#thirdChildObject.objectName = this.objectName3;
    this.#fourthChildObject.objectName = this.objectName4;
    this.#firstChildObject.relationshipFieldName = this.relationshipFieldName;
    this.#secondChildObject.relationshipFieldName = this.relationshipFieldName2;
    this.#thirdChildObject.relationshipFieldName = this.relationshipFieldName3;
    this.#fourthChildObject.relationshipFieldName = this.relationshipFieldName4;
    this.#firstChildObject.fieldsToQuery = this.fieldsToQuery;
    this.#secondChildObject.fieldsToQuery = this.fieldsToQuery2;
    this.#thirdChildObject.fieldsToQuery = this.fieldsToQuery3;
    this.#fourthChildObject.fieldsToQuery = this.fieldsToQuery4;
    this.#firstChildObject.nameOverride = this.nameOverride;
    this.#secondChildObject.nameOverride = this.nameOverride2;
    this.#thirdChildObject.nameOverride = this.nameOverride3;
    this.#fourthChildObject.nameOverride = this.nameOverride4;
    this.#firstChildObject.child = this.#secondChildObject;
    this.#secondChildObject.child = this.#thirdChildObject;
    this.#thirdChildObject.child = this.#fourthChildObject;
    this.newRoot.child = this.#firstChildObject;
    const temp = JSON.stringify(this.newRoot);
    if(temp !== this.configRootStr) {
        this.configRootStr = temp;
    }
  }
  @api imageUrlFieldName;
  @api imageUrlFieldName2;
  @api imageUrlFieldName3;
  @api imageUrlFieldName4;

  //wire method that gets the child records from the Config string entered into the component, and fires every time even one field is entered.
  @wire(getRecords, { configObject: "$configRootStr" })
  wiredData({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.outputList = data;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  }
}
class FormObject {
  constructor() {
    this.objectName = null;
    this.relationshipFieldName = null;
    this.fieldsToQuery = null;
    this.nameOverride = null;
  }
}
```